# Can I tell gcc/ld to exclude unused modules?

Tags: gcc, avr, avr-gcc, avr-studio5

I would like to know if I can tell gcc/ld to omit unused modules from being put into the output file.

Suppose I have modules `a.c`, `b.c` and `c.c`. `a.c` and `b.c` depend on each other, one of them contains a `main()`, and due to whatever reasons, no parts of `c.c` are referenced.

```
gcc -c a.c
gcc -c b.c
gcc -c c.c
```

If I bundle the stuff together into a library, no code from `c.c` won't be in the output:

```
ar rcs abc.a a.o b.o c.o
gcc abc.a
```

But if I give the `.o` files directly to gcc, the code from `c.c` resp. `c.o` is included.

```
gcc a.o b.o c.o
```

Can I, by any way, tell gcc to leave out unused modules without putting them into a library?

I am programming an AVR µC and use AVR Studio, which doesn't allow the creation of libraries, but would like to omit the source files which are not used, depending on the build configuration.

Comment: If you explicitly ask GCC to add c.o, you should not be surprised to have it :)

Comment: That is not me, that's AVR Studio who asks for it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible on AVR, but you could ask GCC to put each symbols in its own section using `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` at compile time. Then at link step, you could use `-Wl,--gc-sections` to ask `ld` to remove unused sections.

Comment: Sounds great. I just found a switch which enables this "gc-sections". Does it as well work on a per-module basis without `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections`? I don't want to get the ISR routines to be thrown out...

Comment: @glglgl according to its name, it's only per sections, not per module. So if your ISR are not referenced by anything in the rest of the code, it's going to be discarded by the linker.

Comment: Oh, I thought that every module has some own sections which get discarded then... After some testing, it turns out that this indeed seems to be the case.

Comment: If you want to know which sections `ld` throws out, you can also add `-Wl,--print-gc-sections` to the linker command line.